# Update service reference - Server Refused 127.0.0.1:Port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

My project has a bunch of projects and some of them consume a WCF one that is in the solution... Every now and then I have to update the service reference and i always get the same message saying that the server actively refused to answer as if there was no service there...

First I start debugging only the WCF project and test it using the WCF Test Client, and everything is fine...
Then, I open another VS instance, without closing the first one, open the same solution (again, not closing the first), start the WCF project, go back to instance 1, and update the service reference without a problem...

I think this is not how it's supposed to work... why can't VS start the WCF project, update the reference and then go on its way? is there a config i'm missing? perhaps something that another team member might have screwed-up in the past?!?

Details:

1. VS 2015
2. All projects on the same solution
3. All projects using same framework version
4. All projects using same architecture ref (x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation (WCF project part of a solution including service consumers) I would not use a service reference. Service references are designed for when you are calling a service over which you have no control and to which you have no access.

You can call the service [directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250(v=vs.110).aspx) using `ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel()` - this removes the need for service references altogether and makes your code simpler and more readable.